# Oracle 11g selecting/inserting multiple max values with one script

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am having trouble selecting/inserting multiple max values with one script.  The following table is made up to represent the combination of values with the tables I am trying to work with.

The script needs to be an insert statement to insert the returned values into a second table.

```
CREATE TABLE family
( state      VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  Birth            date,
  Married       date,
  Shirt size        number(10 )
  Shoe size       number(10),
  Hair                  VARCHAR2(80 BYTE),
  carname                VARCHAR2(24 BYTE),
  CATname               VARCHAR2(24 BYTE),
  Hometown                    VARCHAR2(40 BYTE),
  Alive             CHAR(1 BYTE),
  job_CATEGORY_1        VARCHAR2(40 BYTE),
  job_CATEGORY_2        VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
)
```

This table has over 1500 rows.  I need to select all values from the records with the 
The combination of “Oldest birth date, oldest married date, largest shoe size and largest shirt size”.  The remaining values need to be in the script.

When I select people with the oldest birth date, I get three records with various married dates, and various shirt and shoe size.  My need is to select the combination of max(birth), max(married), max(shirt size) and max(shoe size), then include the remaining columns.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming one record (or maybe a few) will have the max values for all four of those columns? Or do you want the record with the oldest married date (min, not max?) *within* the three records that have the oldest birth date, and so on? I'm not sure I follow quite what you're expecting to end up with. Can you show some sample data and expected results?

Comment: I see your quandry. I added a field (state) So I want the person in Idaho who has all the qualifying max (or min) values... One person per state who has the oldest(or youngest) and largest everything. Adding data would just be an exercise.. this table just represents reality I am working with, but I think that thinking in terms of one record per state may help. Thank you

Comment: But the oldest person won't necessarily have been married the longest, or have the largest shirt or shoe sizes - if one record has to be the max of everything then most states would have no record returned at all?

Comment: Thank you for your help... it is confusing....Each state should have one record. Oldest birth date.  If there is more than one person wioth matching oldest birth date, qualify with the next field, married date.  If there are more than one with equal both dates, qualify with the next field, then if there are more than one, qualify with the last qualifying field,,, then include all the remaining fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm):

```
select * from
(
  select f.*,
    rank() over (partition by state
      order by birth) as birth_rank,
    rank() over (partition by state, birth
      order by married) as married_rank,
    rank() over (partition by state, birth, married
      order by shoe_size desc) as shoe_rank,
    rank() over (partition by state, birth, married, shoe_size
      order by shirt_size desc) as shirt_rank
  from family f
)
where birth_rank = 1
and married_rank = 1
and shoe_rank = 1
and shirt_rank = 1;
```

But instead of `select *` in the outer query, select only the fields you're interested in - you probably don't want to see the rank fields.

Each `_rank` psuedocolumn is [ranking](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions141.htm) the values in the matching column with the group of the preceding ones. So for `birth_rank` it's only looking at the state, and within each state there will be one or more records that get ranked as 1. For `married_rank` it's looking further down, so within each combination of state *and* birth date there will be one married date that is ranked as 1. And so on. The outer query then picks only the highest ranks, and there will usually only be one record per state. (Rank allows ties, so you may need a way to break ties if two or more records meet all the criteria).

The birth and married ranks are ordered ascending so the earliest data is ranked first; the show and shirt size ranks are ordered descending to the largest is ranked first.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4fd3/1), showing the ranks assigned to all the values for all rows in the first query, and then the filter applied in the second query so there is only one row (per state, though I've only included one). This is why sample data is useful.

Comment: Cool... Thank you... And where you have empty parenthesis remain empty ()?

Comment: @user761758 - I've added links to the documentation. For the analytic version of `rank`, it's always `rank()` with empty parentheses, yes.