# Oracle 10g - Return Single Row Based On Max Value of some Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with many columns and many duplicated rows

The primary key composed of C1, C2, Year, C3, C5 columns, and i just want to keep only one row of each duplicated row based on the higher Date, C6 and C4 columns (in this order)

for example : lets take the last 2 rows, based on the 4 columns(our primary key), we have to keep only one of them and to do that : we start with comparing which row have the highest Date column (they have the same date), then we have to move on to the second column (C6) and they have the same value = 0 and in the end we compare C4 column and we take the higher (=1).

for this example we have to chose the last row and delete the other one.

```
C1  C2  Year      C3   C4  C5  C6     Date
------------------------------------------------------------------
100 74  2013    2697    0   1   0   11/06/2013
100 74  2013    2697    1   1   0   11/06/2013
100 74  2013    2697    0   1   1   12/06/2013
100 74  2013    2707        1   0   11/06/2013
100 74  2013    2707        2   0   11/06/2013
100 74  2013    2707        3   0   11/06/2013
100 74  2013    2708    0   1   0   11/06/2013
100 74  2013    2708    1   1   0   11/06/2013
100 74  2013    2708    1   1   1   25/06/2013
100 74  2013    2708    0   1   1   30/06/2013
100 74  2013    3211    0   1   0   28/07/2013
100 74  2013    3211    1   1   0   28/07/2013
```

Thanks

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20526783/266304) might give you some pointers, if I understand what you're doing?

Comment: According to your sample data this statement "The primary key composed of C1, C2, Year, C3, C5 columns" is wrong. Did you mean that you are going to create primary key based on that columns?

Comment: @Yaroslav Shabalin you are right, in this example it's not a primary key but what i need it to keep only one row to eliminate duplicat rows andafter that i have to insert those rows in a another table who respect C1, C2, Year, C3 and C5 as a primary key

Answer (score 0):

General idea:

```
SELECT 
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY c1, c2, year, c3, c5 ORDER BY date, c6, c4) 
FROM table
```

You might want to wrap it in the another SELECT to cut duplicates.